# Visual Studio-Resharper-Stylecop: How to get rid of the indent for property values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

With Visual Studio, Resharper and the StyleCop extension, I always get properties formatted like in the example below when setting there attribute values.

**HINT: Please don't refactor that code. This is explicitly formatted in this way to show the effect!**

```cs
private ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek> WeekDays { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek>
                                                            {
                                                                DayOfWeek.Monday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Thursday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Friday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Saturday,
                                                                DayOfWeek.Sunday
                                                            };
```

However, this really looks ugly for me. How can I tell Resharper / StyleCop to indent this with 4 spaces / 1 tab only?

The example below shows the desired result:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek> WeekDays { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DayOfWeek>
{
    DayOfWeek.Monday,
    DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
    DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
    DayOfWeek.Thursday,
    DayOfWeek.Friday,
    DayOfWeek.Saturday,
    DayOfWeek.Sunday
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off a setting named "Array, object and collection initializer" in a section "Align Multiline Constructs". Just paste that name into a search box in the top left corner of the ReSharper options dialog.

To discover settings affecting your piece of code yourself you can use "Configure formatting" feature. Select a code in question, Alt-Enter > Format selection > Configure...

[image: Configure formatting]

Comment: I will check that and see if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the issue. The "Configure formatting" feature is under `Detect Formatting Settings` in the latest version of Resharper by the way.

Comment: As far as I understand it (and the preview in Resharper shows it), the option `Array, object and collection initializer` should be unchecked for what I want to do...

Comment: Okay, I don't understand this... After saving the settings with the option checked, opening it again and saving it as unchecked, solved this for me... :D Thank you for your help ;)